# From ZFS Array CLI how to get the latest snapshot for share

Tags: storage, zfs, oracle

from ZFS Array cli how to get the latest snapshot for share.

my share name is "test_share" for this share want to check the latest snapshot.

Test-ae0101zfs201:shares test_proj_test/test_share_test snapshots>

Comment: What do you mean by "ZFS Array cli"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking or the full context, but `zfs list -t snap` shows snapshots. They're listed in chronological order, so you can use tail to get the latest one.

`zfs list -t snap | grep test_proj/test_share | tail -1`

Comment: Thanks for replay, command which you have given we need to run from shell prompt. But i am looking the latest snapshot list without entering into shell prompt.                                          ex: once we login into the ZFS Array cli it will be in --   "test-zs0101zfs01>" this prompt right want to get the latest snapshot details for share from here.

Comment: Actually i am looking script for - take snapshot for multiple shares and create clone with the latest snapshot. if you have any script or commands for this it would be helpful for me.

Comment: I don't think I can help you.

Comment: do you have any script to take snapshot for multiple shares and create clone with latest snapshot. if you have any it will help full for me.